# QStandardItemModel & Qtableview

Tags: qt

I am new to qt i am using QStandardItemModel inside QTtableview.

Please suggest,

1. How to change the row & column header names. AT present it is showing 1,2,3,4
2. How to make QStandardItemModel  occupy full Qtableview. At present it is showing at top left corner.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model= new QStandardItemModel(4, 4);
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
            QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0, column %1").arg(row).arg(column));
            model->setItem(row, column, item);
        }
    }

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

1 > `model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(tr("Time")));`

2 > Like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
{
    QList<QStandardItem *> rowData;
    rowData << new QStandardItem(QString("row %1, column %2").arg(row).arg(0))
    rowData << new QStandardItem(QString("row %1, column %2").arg(row).arg(1))
    rowData << new QStandardItem(QString("row %1, column %2").arg(row).arg(2))
    rowData << new QStandardItem(QString("row %1, column %2").arg(row).arg(3))
    model->appendRow(rowData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- There multiple ways to enter headers to a view. I like to do it this way:

```
QStandardItem *infoItem = new QStandardItem("Info");
infoItem ->setFont(heading);
infoItem ->setToolTip("Scene Object Name and Type");

QStandardItem *fileStatus = new QStandardItem();
fileStatus->setIcon(QIcon( ":/icons/fileStatus" ));
fileStatus->setToolTip("File Status displayed by ...");

QStandardItem *fileDirectory = new QStandardItem();
fileDirectory->setIcon( QIcon( ":/icons/directory" ) );
fileDirectory->setToolTip("File directory");

m_model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 0, infoItem );
m_model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 1, fileStatus);
m_model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 2, fileDirectory );
```

2- You can either set the stretch last section to true. This will make sure your last column stretches to fill the table every time you resize the table itself.

```
myView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

or you could set on of your desired columns to stretch enough to fill the table. To do this make sure setStretchLastSection is set to false.

```
myView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(false);
myView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(yourDesiredCol, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Comment: "setResizeMode" is deprecated. Instead, use "setSectionResizeMode"

Answer (score 0):

Use setHorizontalHeaderLabels() and setVerticalHeaderLabels() or setHorizontalHeaderItem() and setVerticalHeaderItem() methods.

The vertical headers are the column names and horizontal headers are the row names.

setVerticalHeaderItem is useful if you want to display more information than a simple text (like a icon or colored text).